# Tensor(1.0).item() vs float(Tensor(1.0))

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

If `x` is a torch.Tensor of dtype torch.float then are the operations `x.item()` and `float(x)` exactly the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operations `x.item()` and `float(x)` are not the same.

From the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.item) of item(), it can be used to get the value of tensor as a Python number(only from tensors containing a single value). It basically returns the value of the tensor as it is. It does not make any modifications to the tensor.

Where as `float()` is for converting its input to a floating point number, when possible. Find the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float).

To see the difference, consider another Tensor y of dtype int64:

```
import torch

y = torch.tensor(2)
print(y, y.dtype)
>>> tensor(2) torch.int64

print('y.item(): {}, float(y): {}'.format(y.item(), float(y)))
>>> y.item(): 2, float(y): 2.0

print(type(y.item()), type(float(y)))
>>> <class 'int'> <class 'float'>
```

Note that `float(y)` does not convert the type in-place. You would need to assign it in case you need that change. Like:

```
z = float(y)
print('y.dtype: {}, type(z): {}'.format(y.dtype, type(z)))
>>> y.dtype: torch.int64, type(z): <class 'float'>
```

We can see that `z` is not a `torch.Tensor`. It is simply a floating point number.

The `float()` operation is not to be confused with `self.float()`. This [operation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.float) performs the Tensor dtype conversion (not in-place, needs assignment).

```
print('y.float(): {},\n y.float().dtype: {},\n y: {},\n y.dtype'.format(y.float(), y.float().dtype, y, y.dtype))

y.float(): 2.0,
y.float().dtype: torch.float32,
y: 2,
y.dtype: torch.int64
```

Comment: Is it safe in all situations to call `float()` directly on a cuda tensor? Just trying it out seems to work...